# Como acceder a los atributos de un arreglo de pointers en parse.com

Tags: javascript, nodejs, parse.com

Tengo el siguiente problema actualmente puedo obtener el [object Object] de cada una orden , sin embargo necesito acceder a sus atributos ya intente con la función include pero no puedo acceder me lo manda undefined

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFwFs.png

Les dejo mi código y espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias

```
exports.pedido = function (req,res){
var currentUser = req.session.user;
    if (currentUser){
        var query_restaurante = new Parse.Query(Restaurante),
                query_historial = new Parse.Query(Historial),
                query_ordenes = new Parse.Query(Orden);
        var restaurante;
        query_restaurante.include("encargado");
        query_restaurante.equalTo("encargado", {__type: "Pointer",className: "_User",objectId: currentUser.objectId});
        query_restaurante.first().then(function(restaurante_encontrado){
            restaurante = restaurante_encontrado;
            query_historial.include("usuario");
            query_historial.include("orden");
            query_historial.equalTo("restaurantes", restaurante);
            return query_historial.find();
            console.log(query_historial)
        }).then(function(historiales){
        var context = {
                title: "Menu",
                restaurante: restaurante,
                historial: historiales,
                logo_restaurante: restaurante.get("logo"),
                rating : restaurante.get("rating"),
                suspender : restaurante.get("suspender"),
                publicidad : restaurante.get("publicidad"),
        };
        return context;
    }).then(function(context){
        res.render('pedidos',context);
        return res;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
}else{
        res.redirect('/');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

no soy un experto en parse.com

Lo primero que debes hacer es un `console.log(JSON.stringify(restaurante_encontrado))` para que veas que atributos tiene y como acceder a ellos. A lo mejor es algo tan simple como `restaurante.atributo_deseado`

saludos

Comment: Cuando no tengas una respuesta concreta o quieres decirle al OP que haga tal cosa para agregar más información; publícalo como comentario.

Comment: Lo siento pero creo que le di la herramienta que necesita el OP para encontrar la solucion a su problema por si solo. No estoy interesado en que me proporcione mas datos sino en que el mismo encuentre la solucion. Saludos

Comment: Cuando respondes es **porque sabes** la razón del problema y su solución. Lo que estás haciendo es **suponer** en donde está el error y, en este caso es mejor hacer un comentario.

Comment: tienes razon en que un comentario sería mas adecuado.